# Why Safari won't stopPropagate click event on video tag?

Tags: javascript

Hi I need help wit this small issue. I have my video in html with onClick function. In this function I am catching event and I am doing stopPropagation on it. This behaviour is good in chrome, opera, firefox etc. But in safari this event.stopPopagation is ignored or what.

I have this function on my video and when i click on video it should run just my own  function. When I turn off controls everything works as I except so it is becouse that e.stopPropagation thing. How to make it work please right in safari too please?

Js

```
function playVideo(e, fullscreen = false){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //Vyber videa tagu
    let activeSlide = (document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-item active")[0]);
    let video = activeSlide.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];


    video.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        video.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }, false);


    if(video.paused ){
        console.log("pause");
        video.play();
        toggleVideoElement(false);
        video.setAttribute("controls","controls")
        if(fullscreen === true){
            openFullscreen(video);
        }
    }
    else{
        video.pause();
        toggleVideoElement(true);
        video.removeAttribute("controls")
    }
    return false;
}
```

Html

```
  <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2 mb-3 mb-xl-0">
                    <div class="video-container position-relative">
                        <i id="play-icon" class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute <?php echo($page->playButtonClass) ?>" onClick=" playVideo(event)"></i>
                        <video preload="false"   onClick=" playVideo(event)" poster="assets/images/foto/<?php echo($page->getVideoPreview()) ?>">
                            <source src="assets/videos/<?php echo($page->getVideoName())?>" type="video/mp4" >
                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Link on my live server for see what the problem is: http://dod.stud.spsknm.sk

Edit:

I tried to add this to my .js and removed onClick from my video tag

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let d = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    console.log(d);
    d.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        playVideo()
    });
});
```

Nothing changed same unwanted behaviour :/

Comment: I’d start by adding the click handler using _proper_ methodology (addEventListener) as well, instead of trying to apply it inline via old-school HTML onclick attribute.

Comment: @CBroe - I don't think onclick is the problem, it works OK.

Comment: onClick method I use in react too it shouldn t be problem

Comment: Could you describe the problem a bit more? When I go to your school site and run the video the behaviour is exactly the same on laptop (Edge browser Windows10) and iPad (Safari IOS14), that is clicking stops the video and restarts it. The only difference is at the beginning because IOS requires a user interaction to get started on the video.

Comment: The `event` variable you are passing in that function call might not be what you expect it to be though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: @AHaworth you can't see the problem on Ipad becouse ipad runs tpuch event not onClick event. This problem is only on safari on mac :/ On touch devices with ios it works fine

Comment: When I push button on video (video will start) and then when i push on video again it stop and start immidiatly ( like when you click two times in a row). I know where the problem probably is... When I inspect video player in safari (with controls on) I see controls are on bottom level of video in DOM. That means that I am clicking on these controls first and then on video element.

Comment: @CBroe I consoled log event from this and it look fine.

Comment: no undef or something

Comment: _“no undef or something”_ - that’s not to be expected either, you are passing in the global `event` object - so that will have all those methods you are trying to call. But that doesn’t say anything about whether it is the _correct_ event you are trying to stop from propagating here.

Comment: @CBroe so what should I do please?

Comment: Try, what I suggested with the very first comment already?

Comment: So I have to add this event to my video when document load?

Comment: @CBroe I edited post but nothing changed

Comment: Also as I ment when I remove controls of video everything works as I exepect. When click on video it start when click again it stop so it has to be problem with that controls. One possibility is to do own controls for every browser but there has to  be other way

Comment: Try adding the onClick event to the parent DIV tag instead of the VIDEO tag - the DIV with the video-container class